# Two's complement of a number

Tags: c, binary, numbers, binary-data

As far as I know, if I want to represent -1 in binary form, then:

1. I'll first look for the binary representation of 1 which is 0001.
2. Then I'll find one's complement (invert all 0's and 1's) to get 1110.
3. Then add 1 to least significant bit and get 1111. which is my answer.

However I have a doubt that if I represent 1 (in step number 1) as 001 (I believe we can do this), then one's complement would be 110 and adding 1 would yield me 111 which is different from what I obtained previously.

How do you explain this difference?

Comment: Think of it as you have `N` available bits, and that provides a total range from 0 to 2^N - 1.  But you want to allow negatives so you divide the value space in half -- one half for positives and one half for negatives.  To achieve this you sacrifice one bit.  In one's complement it's very easy, but there's a problem because there becomes two representations for zero (+0 is all 0-bits and -0 is all 1-bits).  Two's complement gets around this by then adding 1, which allows one additional negative number to exist.

Comment: Your reasoning is good, The only diffrence is in the number of bits you used to represent integers.

Answer (score 0):

The twos-complement representation of -1 is "all 1s".

However many places are in your number representation set all of them to 1 and that is the two's complement of 1.

For more details look up "sign extending".

Comment: So, do you mean that the representation of (-1) will be different on 16 bit and 32 bit systems because number of bits is different.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the size. For example, a negative `int` is 32 1's while for a `char` it is only 8 1`s.

Comment: The representation isn't really different, unless you say that the representation of +1 is different as well.  is 001 different from 00001?  Just the same as you imagine positive numbers as having infinitely many zeros in front of them, negative numbers have infinitely many ones in front of them (but only a certain number of them fit in your type).